# As a regular user, post to sharepoint list

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm just a regular user in the company I work for, but I'm trying to automate posting to a SharePoint list, but I can't figure out how with my limited access and older PowerShell version on the computer. Here are some things I've come across which I don't believe I have access to as a normal end user with limited credentials and rights (I can access and input to the sharepoint list manually though):

- #Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
  Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
- #Connect-PnPOnline
- #Get-SPWeb
- #Add PSsnapin
  Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

I've also tried some other methods like opening an invisible Internet Explorer and manipulate the Com object with new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application" but that opens the new chromium edge which doesn't allow you to navigate and submit from powershell commands.

The link to my list name which I have to mundanely enter form after form manually is as follows:

- https://ourCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/myTeamSubsite/furthersubsite/Lists/TheListName/AllItems.aspx
- The new form entry is similar with the end location as the following instead:
  /TheListName/NewForm.aspx

I saw an old post using New-WebServiceProxy such as:

```
$wsdlUrl = $siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $wsdlUrl -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, (ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force)))
```

Though every time I try to access the list with $proxy.GetList('TheListName') I get some error about access denied, and I've triple checked and tried all combinations of domain username and my password that I know of.

What options are left for me to automate my manual entry into this sharepoint form? I know there is an API and we do have 0365, but how would I find out if the API for this is open to an end user like me?

Answer (score 0):

From the context of your question, I am going to consider you are interacting with SharePoint Online.

The following routes are available, but incur different issues (authentication, context, authorization from admin, ...):

1 - PowerShell - No framework - Kind of the example you showed, but without `Connect-PnPOnline` since it belongs to the PnP framework. It requires you to have the SharePoint Server DLLs installed on your computer, which should not be by default.

2 - PowerShell - PnP.Powershell module. It requires an admin to have consented on your tenant. Once this is done, you can use it (`Connect-PnPOnline`, `Add-PnPListItem`) with your credentials as a normal user. It is even compatible with MFA Accounts.

3 - PowerShell - SharePointPnPSharePointOnline. Old version of the previous one, but does not require an administrator approval on the tenant level. Almost the same commands, should be the same for your needs.

All three of the previous options require a PowerShell 5.1 to my knowledge (so Win 10 or newer).

4 - SharePoint Rest Api. You may use your open SharePoint page to make Web Calls in JS. This is great as your are already authenticated, but still requires a bit of knowledge. Example: in DevTools (F12), you may write `fetch('<my-site-url>/_api/web', { credentials: "include", headers: { accept: "application/json" } }).then(r => r.json()).then(console.log)` to retrieve the current web properties. Adding an item would be a different endpoint which requires a pre-call to retrieve a RequestDigest beforehand.

5 - SharePoint Rest Api + pnp framework for JS. Either scripting using a NodeJS project or with an in-navigator code editor (using SP Editor extension for Chrome), you will be able to enjoy a one-liner to add an item without a need for PowerShell. I recommend the extension as you will not have to write any authentication. In this extension (F12 > SharePoint > PnPJS console) you will have a VSCode like window which allows you to script using the authenticated user, not requiring any admin right. There, you may enter for example:

`sp.web.lists.getByTitle('<list-name>').items.add({ Title: "Hello World!" })`
Which will create a new list item with `Hello World!` as a Title in the list `list-name`.

Less code savvy people may recommand you the Power Platform for your needs, I will let them present to you that kind of approach which may also interest you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I looked at SharePointPnPSharePointOnline, but I don't have it installed checked by using it and Get-Module -ListAvailable "SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline". To install I need admin rights. 

I don't have access to make changes to the pages like add JS to it in the page. Is there any way to authenticate with the API with user permissions and use powershell with Invoke-Webrequest? I found some sources, but you need an app secret api key to authenticate.

Comment: for methods 4 and 5, you actually just use your JS Console in your Navigator devtools (F12). Anybody can do that on any site. I can script this current page to retrieve any text and comment on it. And on SharePoint, you can consume its REST API when you're on any page of the site. try my `fetch` example, you will see. For PowerShell you can do what the module does, but you really don't want to have to implement everything by yourself. You could also probably download the module and load it from a folder instead of trying to install it on your machine using admin rights.